# I can't enter text into a text file

Tags: python, file, text, text-files

I cannot enter text into a file and I'm not sure if it is different because I am on mac not windows but whatever I do it won't work, please help.

```
try:
    with open('inf.txt', 'a') as outFile:
        name = input('Full Name - ')
        outFile.write(name + '\n')
except:
    print('no work - 1')
```

Comment: what error are you getting? don't capture the exception, let the program crash so the exception will tell you the error (or if you want to capture the exception, print the message that the exception launches, don't capture bare exceptions like this). In your code you are masking valuable information and just printing `'no work - 1'` which is not very useful

Comment: even with just the 'with' statement it doesn't even write into the file, im not sure why, and im getting no errors at all, the code seems to be executing but not writing into the file

Comment: so when you open the `inf.txt` file it remains with the same contents? Make sure your viewer is refreshing the contents of the file and that you are not opening a file with the same name from another folder

Comment: yes the contents don't change, im able to open the file and edit it and manually write whatever but the code isn't entering text into the file

Comment: that's very strange. Can you follow what I posted in the answer and confirm if you see `Alice` and `Bob` written in the file?

Comment: Thank you for the help but I ended up figgureing it out, it was creating a new file with the same name and using that one, why it wasn't using the one I already created I'm not sure but thank you so mch for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If the code runs without the exception handling and throws no errors, then your file is probably being written correctly.

Try this: adding a code that reads the file after writing to it.

```
with open('inf.txt', 'a') as outFile:
    name = input('Full Name - ')
    outFile.write(name + '\n')

print("The contents of the file are:")
with open('inf.txt', 'r') as inFile:
    for line in inFile:
        print(line)
```

Now delete the file `inf.txt` to start clean and execute the program once, and typing `Alice`, you should see:

```
The contents of the file are:
Alice
```

Run the program again and input `Bob`, you should see:

```
The contents of the file are:
Alice
Bob
```